# How to configure Glassfish 3.1 to host a web application

Tags: glassfish-3

Does anyone know how to configure glassfish 3.1 to host a web application? I have a web app deployed in my glassfish server which i want to access from the internet. I do not want to install and configure a web server/load balancer.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't see the server you deploy Glassfish to from the Internet, you can't see your app.

I doubt that you want to expose your app server directly to the Internet.  Why don't you want to use a web server?  Usually the web server is put in a DMZ and exposed to the Internet; it relays requests into the app server.

None of this has anything to do with Glassfish.  It's about what you do with your servers and configuration.

Comment: I ended up installing and configuring mod_jk which works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  First get the required zip file from the internet

```
Sudo wget http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/release/glassfish-5.0.1.zip
```

*Note: change the version as required*

Step 2: unzip the file in the location where you want to install the glassfish server

```
unzip glassfish-5.0.1.zip
```

Step 3: Then go inside of the installed location in the /bin folder and run the asadmin file in the terminal using

```
./asadmin
```

Example: `sagar@sagar-X556UA:~/software/glassfish3Ok/glassfish3/bin$ ./asadmin`

Step 4: Then asadmin bash will open. Then type: start -domain inside of it

asadmin -> start-domain

Step 5: Then the glassfish will run in the default port. i.e., 8080, Goto google, or any browser and type:

```
Localhost:8080
```

And Glassfish admin panel will run in the  port i.e., 4848 (if not you will see the port number of admin after you start the domain)

```
Localhost:4848
```

**Integrate the glassfish server in the netbeans**

- Select Tools -> Servers to open the Servers dialog.
- Click Add Server.
- Under Choose Server, select GlassFish v3 and click Next.
- Under Server Location, browse the location of your GlassFish Server
  installation and click Next.
- Under Domain Location, select Register Local Domain.
- Click Finish.